# How to add suffix to mogrify - imagemagick

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick, mogrify

I'm running this command to create thumbnails with mogrify and it works great!

```
#! /bin/bash
 mogrify             \
-resize 300x300     \
-crop 200x200+0-20 \
-gravity center   \
-format jpg       \
-quality 100       \
-path thumbs      \
 *.jpg
```

But what I would like to add is a suffix to the output filenames like. -avatar
So the output image name is changed from testimage.jpg to testimage-avatar.jpg.

Thanks all!

Comment: Try with `convert` : http://superuser.com/questions/597428/how-can-i-run-mogrify-but-prefix-the-filename.

Comment: Hi, saw now that I need to use convert to change the name. Now I just need to figure it how to add a suffix instead of prefix.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with `mogrify`, but you can use `convert`:

```
convert result.png -set filename:new '%t-avatar' %[filename:new].jpg
```

and you would have to put it in a loop over all JPEG files:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.jpg; do
   convert "$f" -set filename:new "%t-avatar" "%[filename:new].jpg"
done
```

Alternatively, you could retain your original `mogrify` command - which is actually more efficient than `convert` and then go into the `thumbs` directory afterwards and use `rename` to put the `avatar` bit in:

```
rename --dry-run -X --append="-avatar" *.jpg
```

**Sample Output**

```
'a.jpg' would be renamed to 'a-avatar.jpg'
'image.jpg' would be renamed to 'image-avatar.jpg'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm with rename :)

Comment: Not sure if this is intended for Windows but on Windows 10, for the rename command it returns `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: @AdamJagosz Correct, it is not for Windows - the question was tagged `linux` and `bash`. Sorry.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Right... I ran this in my WSL (Ubuntu), installed `rename` and got ```Unknown option: dry-run
Unknown option: X
Unknown option: append```

Comment: @AdamJagosz There are several packages with a `rename` utility. The one you want is also referred to as `prename`, `Perl rename` or `Larry Wall rename` as it's a Perl script.